# macbook 2016 21w charger replaced with 61watt

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I have a late 2016 macbook with a charger that fails often.  I bought one that I thought would work but am afraid to try it until I know for sure.They are both c chargers, but the original one is 29W and the new one is 61w. I think that using one with higher wattage is ok, am I right?

Comment: "I have a late 2016 macbook with a charger that fails often."  Is it a *genuine* Apple charger?

Answer (score 1):

From: [Find the right power adapter and cable for your Mac notebook](https://support.apple.com/HT201700)

> Power adapters for Mac notebooks are available in 29W, 30W, 45W, 60W,
> 61W, 85W, 87W, and 96W varieties. You should use the appropriate
> wattage power adapter for your Mac notebook. You can use a compatible
> higher wattage power adapter without issue, but it won't make your
> computer charge faster or operate differently.

Also:

> **Make sure you're using the correct USB-C charge cable**
>
> For the best charging experience, you should use the USB-C charge
> cable that comes with your Mac notebook. If you use a higher wattage
> USB-C cable, your Mac will still charge normally. USB-C cables rated
> for 29W or 30W will work with any USB-C power adapter, but won't
> provide enough power when connected to a power adapter that is more
> than 61W, such as the 96W USB-C Power Adapter.